# Chu-Liu Edmond's algorithm for Minimum Spanning Tree on Directed Graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, tree

I would like to find a minimum spanning tree (MST) on a weighted directed graph.  I have been trying to use [Chu-Liu/Edmond's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm), which I have implemented in Python (code below).  A simple, clear description of the algorithm can be found [here](http://www.ce.rit.edu/~sjyeec/dmst.html).  I have two questions.

1. Is Edmond's algorithm guaranteed to converge on a solution?

   I am concerned that removing a cycle will add another cycle. If this happens, the algorithm will continue trying to remove cycles forever.

   I seem to have found an example where this happens.  The input graph is shown below (in the code).  The algorithm never finishes because it switches between cycles [1,2] and [1,3], and [5,4] and [5,6].  The edge added to the graph to resolve the cycle [5,4] creates cycle [5,6] and vice versa, and similarly for [1,2] and [1,3].

   I should note that I am not certain that my implementation is correct.
2. To resolve this issue, I introduced an ad hoc patch.  When an edge is removed to remove a cycle, I permanently remove that edge from the underlying graph G on which we are searching for an MST.  Consequently, that edge cannot be added again and this should prevent the algorithm from getting stuck.  With this change, am I guaranteed to find an MST?

   I suspect that one can find a pathological case where this step will lead to a result that is not an MST, but I have not been able to think of one.  It seems to work on all the simple test cases that I have tried.

Code:

```
import sys

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

def _reverse(graph):
    r = {}
    for src in graph:
        for (dst,c) in graph[src].items():
            if dst in r:
                r[dst][src] = c
            else:
                r[dst] = { src : c }
    return r

# Finds all cycles in graph using Tarjan's algorithm
def strongly_connected_components(graph):
    """
    Tarjan's Algorithm (named for its discoverer, Robert Tarjan) is a graph theory algorithm
    for finding the strongly connected components of a graph.

    Based on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm
    """

    index_counter = [0]
    stack = []
    lowlinks = {}
    index = {}
    result = []

    def strongconnect(node):
        # set the depth index for this node to the smallest unused index
        index[node] = index_counter[0]
        lowlinks[node] = index_counter[0]
        index_counter[0] += 1
        stack.append(node)

        # Consider successors of `node`
        try:
            successors = graph[node]
        except:
            successors = []
        for successor in successors:
            if successor not in lowlinks:
                # Successor has not yet been visited; recurse on it
                strongconnect(successor)
                lowlinks[node] = min(lowlinks[node],lowlinks[successor])
            elif successor in stack:
                # the successor is in the stack and hence in the current strongly connected component (SCC)
                lowlinks[node] = min(lowlinks[node],index[successor])

        # If `node` is a root node, pop the stack and generate an SCC
        if lowlinks[node] == index[node]:
            connected_component = []

            while True:
                successor = stack.pop()
                connected_component.append(successor)
                if successor == node: break
            component = tuple(connected_component)
            # storing the result
            result.append(component)

    for node in graph:
        if node not in lowlinks:
            strongconnect(node)

    return result

def _mergeCycles(cycle,G,RG,g,rg):
    allInEdges = [] # all edges entering cycle from outside cycle
    minInternal = None
    minInternalWeight = sys.maxint

    # Find minimal internal edge weight
    for n in cycle:
        for e in RG[n]:
            if e in cycle:
                if minInternal is None or RG[n][e] < minInternalWeight:
                    minInternal = (n,e)
                    minInternalWeight = RG[n][e]
                    continue
            else:
                allInEdges.append((n,e)) # edge enters cycle

    # Find the incoming edge with minimum modified cost
    # modified cost c(i,k) = c(i,j) - (c(x_j, j) - min{j}(c(x_j, j)))
    minExternal = None
    minModifiedWeight = 0
    for j,i in allInEdges: # j is vertex in cycle, i is candidate vertex outside cycle
        xj, weight_xj_j = rg[j].popitem() # xj is vertex in cycle that currently goes to j
        rg[j][xj] = weight_xj_j # put item back in dictionary
        w = RG[j][i] - (weight_xj_j - minInternalWeight) # c(i,k) = c(i,j) - (c(x_j, j) - min{j}(c(x_j, j)))
        if minExternal is None or w <= minModifiedWeight:
            minExternal = (j,i)
            minModifiedWeight = w

    w = RG[minExternal[0]][minExternal[1]] # weight of edge entering cycle
    xj,_ = rg[minExternal[0]].popitem() # xj is vertex in cycle that currently goes to j
    rem = (minExternal[0], xj) # edge to remove
    rg[minExternal[0]].clear() # popitem() should delete the one edge into j, but we ensure that

    # Remove offending edge from RG
    # RG[minExternal[0]].pop(xj, None) #highly experimental. throw away the offending edge, so we never get it again

    if rem[1] in g:
        if rem[0] in g[rem[1]]:
            del g[rem[1]][rem[0]]
    if minExternal[1] in g:
        g[minExternal[1]][minExternal[0]] = w
    else:
        g[minExternal[1]] = { minExternal[0] : w }

    rg = _reverse(g)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

def mst(root,G):
    """ The Chu-Liu/Edmond's algorithm

    arguments:

    root - the root of the MST
    G - the graph in which the MST lies

    returns: a graph representation of the MST

    Graph representation is the same as the one found at:
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466/

    Explanation is copied verbatim here:

    The input graph G is assumed to have the following
    representation: A vertex can be any object that can
    be used as an index into a dictionary.  G is a
    dictionary, indexed by vertices.  For any vertex v,
    G[v] is itself a dictionary, indexed by the neighbors
    of v.  For any edge v->w, G[v][w] is the length of
    the edge.
    """

    RG = _reverse(G)

    g = {}
    for n in RG:
        if len(RG[n]) == 0:
            continue
        minimum = sys.maxint
        s,d = None,None

        for e in RG[n]:
            if RG[n][e] < minimum:
                minimum = RG[n][e]
                s,d = n,e

        if d in g:
            g[d][s] = RG[s][d]
        else:
            g[d] = { s : RG[s][d] }

    cycles = [list(c) for c in strongly_connected_components(g)]

    cycles_exist = True
    while cycles_exist:

        cycles_exist = False
        cycles = [list(c) for c in strongly_connected_components(g)]
        rg = _reverse(g)

        for cycle in cycles:

            if root in cycle:
                continue

            if len(cycle) == 1:
                continue

            _mergeCycles(cycle, G, RG, g, rg)
            cycles_exist = True

    return g

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # an example of an input that works
    root = 0
    g = {0: {1: 23, 2: 22, 3: 22}, 1: {2: 1, 3: 1}, 3: {1: 1, 2: 0}}

    # an example of an input that causes infinite cycle
    root = 0
    g = {0: {1: 17, 2: 16, 3: 19, 4: 16, 5: 16, 6: 18}, 1: {2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 11, 5: 10, 6: 12}, 2: {1: 3, 3: 4, 4: 8, 5: 8, 6: 11}, 3: {1: 3, 2: 4, 4: 12, 5: 11, 6: 14}, 4: {1: 11, 2: 8, 3: 12, 5: 6, 6: 10}, 5: {1: 10, 2: 8, 3: 11, 4: 6, 6: 4}, 6: {1: 12, 2: 11, 3: 14, 4: 10, 5: 4}}

    h = mst(int(root),g)

    print h

    for s in h:
        for t in h[s]:
            print "%d-%d" % (s,t)
```

Comment: On page 46 of [Dependency Parsing](http://books.google.com/books?id=k3iiup7HB9UC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=chu+liu+edmond%27s+algorithm+guaranteed?&source=bl&ots=z8I6KOJdDY&sig=UMz6lj_9dIyKOPC25cYlehiStpU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fW2JU-PIKo-JogSJtYHoAg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=chu%20liu%20edmond's%20algorithm%20guaranteed%3F&f=true), the Edmond's algorithm is described.  It can be implemented recursively by running the algorithm on the contracted graph during the cycle removal step, then expanding the contracted cycles at the end.  This raises the question: Is my non-recursive implementation equivalent?

Comment: My strategy is to discard the edge that creates the cycle, then continue removing cycles until there are none remaining.  Is this equivalent to recursively calling Edmond's algorithm on the contracted graph?

Comment: The "simple, clear description of the algorithm" 's link is broken. Please review it.

Comment: @user2398029 What are you trying to accomplish with your bounty?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat get specific credible answers to the questions asked by the OP

Comment: @user2398029 I can't speak for the other people knowledgeable enough to answer this question, but I for one am completely uninterested in debugging an alternative to Chu--Liu/Edmonds that was proposed for no particular reason.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat That's fine, but it is an important algorithm and there's no good standalone Python implementation on the web, which is why I think this question has value.

Comment: How can you break cycles before you have found the MST of the contracted graph? How do you know which edge to remove? You are breaking an assumption of the algorithm, which results in gibberish. In short: No it is not equivalent.

Comment: @user2398029 OK, that's more like it.

Answer (score 9):

Don't do ad hoc patches. I concede that implementing the contraction/uncontraction logic is not intuitive, and recursion is undesirable in some contexts, so here's a proper Python implementation that could be made production quality. Rather than perform the uncontraction step at each recursive level, we defer it to the end and use depth-first search, thereby avoiding recursion. (The correctness of this modification follows ultimately from complementary slackness, part of the theory of linear programming.)

The naming convention below is that `_rep` signifies a supernode (i.e., a block of one or more contracted nodes).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple


Arc = namedtuple('Arc', ('tail', 'weight', 'head'))


def min_spanning_arborescence(arcs, sink):
    good_arcs = []
    quotient_map = {arc.tail: arc.tail for arc in arcs}
    quotient_map[sink] = sink
    while True:
        min_arc_by_tail_rep = {}
        successor_rep = {}
        for arc in arcs:
            if arc.tail == sink:
                continue
            tail_rep = quotient_map[arc.tail]
            head_rep = quotient_map[arc.head]
            if tail_rep == head_rep:
                continue
            if tail_rep not in min_arc_by_tail_rep or min_arc_by_tail_rep[tail_rep].weight > arc.weight:
                min_arc_by_tail_rep[tail_rep] = arc
                successor_rep[tail_rep] = head_rep
        cycle_reps = find_cycle(successor_rep, sink)
        if cycle_reps is None:
            good_arcs.extend(min_arc_by_tail_rep.values())
            return spanning_arborescence(good_arcs, sink)
        good_arcs.extend(min_arc_by_tail_rep[cycle_rep] for cycle_rep in cycle_reps)
        cycle_rep_set = set(cycle_reps)
        cycle_rep = cycle_rep_set.pop()
        quotient_map = {node: cycle_rep if node_rep in cycle_rep_set else node_rep for node, node_rep in quotient_map.items()}


def find_cycle(successor, sink):
    visited = {sink}
    for node in successor:
        cycle = []
        while node not in visited:
            visited.add(node)
            cycle.append(node)
            node = successor[node]
        if node in cycle:
            return cycle[cycle.index(node):]
    return None


def spanning_arborescence(arcs, sink):
    arcs_by_head = defaultdict(list)
    for arc in arcs:
        if arc.tail == sink:
            continue
        arcs_by_head[arc.head].append(arc)
    solution_arc_by_tail = {}
    stack = arcs_by_head[sink]
    while stack:
        arc = stack.pop()
        if arc.tail in solution_arc_by_tail:
            continue
        solution_arc_by_tail[arc.tail] = arc
        stack.extend(arcs_by_head[arc.tail])
    return solution_arc_by_tail


print(min_spanning_arborescence([Arc(1, 17, 0), Arc(2, 16, 0), Arc(3, 19, 0), Arc(4, 16, 0), Arc(5, 16, 0), Arc(6, 18, 0), Arc(2, 3, 1), Arc(3, 3, 1), Arc(4, 11, 1), Arc(5, 10, 1), Arc(6, 12, 1), Arc(1, 3, 2), Arc(3, 4, 2), Arc(4, 8, 2), Arc(5, 8, 2), Arc(6, 11, 2), Arc(1, 3, 3), Arc(2, 4, 3), Arc(4, 12, 3), Arc(5, 11, 3), Arc(6, 14, 3), Arc(1, 11, 4), Arc(2, 8, 4), Arc(3, 12, 4), Arc(5, 6, 4), Arc(6, 10, 4), Arc(1, 10, 5), Arc(2, 8, 5), Arc(3, 11, 5), Arc(4, 6, 5), Arc(6, 4, 5), Arc(1, 12, 6), Arc(2, 11, 6), Arc(3, 14, 6), Arc(4, 10, 6), Arc(5, 4, 6)], 0))
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or does this fail on A->B A->C?

Comment: Also, e.g. [Arc(1, 0, 8),Arc(8, 1, 2),Arc(2, 1, 6),Arc(6, 1, 3),Arc(1, 1, 4)]

Comment: @user2398029 I'm assuming that the arborescence should be oriented rootward, so A->B A->C has no solution.

Comment: How would one go about modifying the above for the away-from-root case?

Comment: @user2398029 Swap `head` and `tail` in the definition of `Arc`. Rename `sink` to `source` for consistency.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - How can we modify the code to find a `maximum spanning tree`. We use the maximum spanning tree algorithm for [dependency parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar). I have changed `<` condition to `>`. Additioanlly I find that, the in the method `spanning_arborescence(arcs, sink)`,  instead of popping the last element in the stack, I should pop the first element by modifying the code to `stack.pop(0)`. I tried the said modification on a number of samples. Still I cannot confirm whether the same is correct or not. Can you please look into it.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - In this graph input, `[Arc(1, 9, 0), Arc(2, 10, 0), Arc(3, 9, 0), Arc(2, 20, 1), Arc(3, 3, 1), Arc(1, 30, 2), Arc(3, 11, 2), Arc(2, 0, 3), Arc(1, 30, 3)], 0)`, ideally the spanning tree must have weights 10,30,30. Just a small correction that I have changed `>` in original code to `<` in the `min_spanning_arborescence(arcs, sink)` method

Comment: @AmrithKrishna I haven't looked at this code in a while. Why don't you generate random small test cases and compare the result against a brute force method?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but the following recursive implementation of Edmond's algorithm seems to be working as expected:

[graph.py](https://code.google.com/p/python-depparse/source/browse/graph.py?spec=svn7e7608fb9d5fa397e6df7ae0f2fae4e983bc15ba&r=7e7608fb9d5fa397e6df7ae0f2fae4e983bc15ba)

**NOTE** that the mst() method returns a Maximum Spanning Tree in this implementation. Hopefully this code could be used as a reference to adjust your implementation.

Comment: There are some troubles on your link graph.py, I cannot see it.